# How would I access a variable defined in solidity from my `JS` script

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing

I am trying to write test for a function `addPerson()` that takes `stirng` name and `uint256` favNumber and creates a `People` object and add it to the `people` list, this `addPerson()` is defined in `Solidity` and I am trying to access it in my "test-deploy.js", here's the test I have written -

```
  it("It should add People object to people list and nameToFavNum", async function () {
    const expectedValue = ["name", "87"]
    const transactionResponse = await simpleStorage.addPerson("name", 87)
    await transactionResponse.wait(1)
    const actualValue = await simpleStorage.people[0]
    
    assert.equal(expectedValue, actualValue)
  })
```

Now here `actualValue` returns `undefined` it works well on other functions that return something, I need to grab that value which I store on calling `addPerson()` the code for `addPerson()` -

```
    function addPerson (string memory _name, uint256 _favNum) public {
        People memory newPerson = People({name: _name, favNum: _favNum});
        people.push(newPerson);
        nameToFavNum[_name] = _favNum;
    }
```

I tried my best to explain my problem and if anyone could help me with this it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: So there is an array called `people` which is of type struct. If that's the case, then you should be able to access it almost as you do, just one small change: `await simpleStorage.people(0)`. Make sure the variable is `public`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `const actualValue = await simpleStorage.people[0]` to `const actualValue = await simpleStorage.people(0)`